# Could someone explain where BatchNorm is performed in ResNeXT https://github.com/facebookresearch/ResNeXt neural network?

Tags: facebook, neural-network, conv-neural-network, resnet, deep-residual-networks

I was reading the original paper that described ResNeXT   (variation of Resnet) at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05431.pdf.

On Page-5 top right column, it says:

> ReLU is performed right after eachBN, expect for the output of the
>   block where ReLU is per-formed after the adding to the shortcut,
>   following [14].

This sentence doesn't make sense, esp the part after comma "expect for the output of....".

- Could someone explain what this sentence means?
- Where is BN performed?

Comment: answered at stats.SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460257/where-is-batchnorm-performed-in-resnext-https-github-com-facebookresearch-resn/460426#460426

Answer (score 0):

ResNeXt uses the same conv-bn-relu policy as ResNet. Scheme is following:

[image: BN-ReLu order]

You can check scheme for ResNet in official [ResNet repo](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/gist/db945b393d40bfa26006).

Probably you were confused by the typo in the paper: the word "expect" you should read as "except".